# How to find out the version of deployed jsf application?

Tags: jsf

I built an JSF application on **apache-tomcat**.When I checked the apis it is not mentioned any version on that(for jstl and jsf jars).Even I tried with MANIFEST.MF in META-INF folder but except manifest version(Manifest-Version: 1.0) nothing was mentioned there.
 Then how to find out Which version of JSF I am using?

Comment: What's the timestamp of the class files inside the JSF API/impl JAR files? What's the `version` in `<faces-config>` root declaration of your webapp's `faces-config.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

`Bundle-Version` must be added in any JSF jars. If you couldn't find that in your jars, you may downloaded wrong one.

If your project is maven built, you can find everything in `pom.xml`. Here is a JSF download link

[Oracle Mojarra JavaServer Faces.](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html)

Comment: I dont think jars are wrong ones because application is working fine.

Comment: even our-self can build own jsf jars by using jsf source codes. if someone built like that, may be not included relevant information in manifest. that is what i said wrong one.